# how to extract binaries from SOHO routers and other devices

Tags: router, reverse-engineering

I read this [excellent article about vulnerability research into a DLINK wireless router](https://www.fortinet.com/blog/threat-research/d-link-routers-found-vulnerable-rce.html).  The researcher explains clearly the coding mistake that leads to the vulnerability.  He obviously reverse-engineered a binary running on the device  but skips a step in how he acquired the code:

> The login action is performed via the URI /apply_sec.cgi. A quick search reveals that the apply_sec.cgi code is located at function do_ssc (0x40a210) in the /www/cgi/ssi binary.

What are some methods for acquiring these binaries (that is, the firmware)?  I've been learning how to use Ghidra.  Looking at vulnerable binaries from routers would be a good learning exercise.

Comment: The firmware?  Often the manufacturer has the firmware updates available on their website for download. What device specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Yes, the firmware.  I edited the question to make that clearer.  The device in question is a ZyXEL FR1000Z

Comment: The CenturyLink site has firmware updates for this router but I'm more interested in the old, vulnerable firmware version that exists on the device.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the already-mentioned option of pulling and extracting firmware updates, most routers offer a command-line admin interface, available over SSH or even Telnet. Connect to this interface, and you'll be dropped into what is *supposed* to be a secure, restricted shell. In practice, the shell will almost certainly have some way to do command injection (for example, on some routers, running any allowed command followed by `$(command)` or even `; command` will work).

Once you've got command injection, verify that you're root (quite likely). At that point, you can use common Linux commands (the device will have a limited command selection but you should be able to find what you need) to get a way to copy binary files. Extract individual binaries and/or entire volume images to your PC through that, and analyze them to your heart's content.

If you aren't root, you'll need to find a local EoP vulnerability on the router; these are common enough in Linux that old firmware will almost certainly have some, though you might need to compile the exploit for your specific platform. I've yet to see a SOHO router where I needed to do this; though.